# CSS: Resizing div to fit absolutely positioned contents

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble trying to get a div (#playlist in blue) to resize to fit another div (.clipdiv in pink).

The code below shows my issue:

```css
html, body {
 background-color: black;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 160px auto;
 grid-template-rows: 16px calc(100vh - 16px);
}
.clip {
 background-color: magenta;
 cursor: move;
 height: 32px;
 outline: 1px solid white;
 position: relative;
}
.clipdiv {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
}
#mainnav {
 background-color: green;
 overflow: scroll;
}
#playlist {
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#sidenav {
 background-color: yellow;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
 overflow: scroll;
 padding: 8px;
}
#topnav {
 background-color: red;
 border-bottom: 2px solid white;
 grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
.track {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 display: flex;
 height: 32px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <body>
  <div id="topnav"></div>
  <div id="sidenav"></div>
  <div id="mainnav">
   <div id="playlist">
    <div class="track">
     <div class="clipdiv" style="left: 640px;">
      <canvas class="clip" width="417" height="128"></canvas>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track"></div>
    <div class="track"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Everything looks OK until the page is scrolled to the right. The blue divs are too short. I am hoping to resize the blue divs to be the width of the green div, so the pink div is inside the blue divs.

Comment: Having a hard time understanding the effect you're going for.  You want the first blue div to be inside of the pink div?

Comment: Sorry, I will try to explain better - I am trying to get the blue divs to accommodate the pink div. The blue divs are too short, as they should be the width of the green div. I am basically trying to stop the blue divs from cutting off at the end.

Comment: The pink div has ```position: absolute``` on it with a static ```left``` property of 640px, so when the window shrinks to less than that width, the pink div will still be outside it.  It's still tough to tell the exact setup you want because it's abstract, but if you set ```left``` to a relative value, say 50%, it will not exceed the width of the blue div when the window gets smaller.  I'll make a snippet to see if that's what you mean.

Comment: The pink div represents an audio clip while the blue divs represent audio tracks - the pink div should be free to move everywhere along (and past) the tracks - it's just difficult because I am hoping to resize the tracks regardless of where the clip is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming up with a JavaScript hack to force the playlist to continue indefinitely:

```js
var playlist;
var playlistWidth = 0;

function setup() {
 playlist = document.getElementById("playlist");
 playlistWidth = playlist.scrollWidth;
}

function updateWidth(elem) {
 playlist.style.width = playlistWidth + elem.scrollLeft + "px";
}
```

```css
html, body {
 background-color: black;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 160px auto;
 grid-template-rows: 16px calc(100vh - 16px);
}
.clip {
 background-color: magenta;
 cursor: move;
 height: 32px;
 outline: 1px solid white;
 position: relative;
}
.clipdiv {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
}
#mainnav {
 background-color: green;
 overflow: scroll;
}
#playlist {
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#sidenav {
 background-color: yellow;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
 overflow: scroll;
 padding: 8px;
}
#topnav {
 background-color: red;
 border-bottom: 2px solid white;
 grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
.track {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 display: flex;
 height: 32px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <body onload="setup();">
  <div id="topnav"></div>
  <div id="sidenav"></div>
  <div id="mainnav" onscroll="updateWidth(this);">
   <div id="playlist">
    <div class="track">
     <div class="clipdiv" style="left: 640px;">
      <canvas class="clip" width="417" height="128"></canvas>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track"></div>
    <div class="track"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, is this what you mean by staying within the blue div?  Just make sure you're using a relative value for the pink div's `left` position.

```css
html, body {
 background-color: black;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 160px auto;
 grid-template-rows: 16px calc(100vh - 16px);
}
.clip {
 background-color: magenta;
 cursor: move;
 height: 32px;
 outline: 1px solid white;
 position: relative;
}
.clipdiv {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
}
#mainnav {
 background-color: green;
 overflow: scroll;
}
#playlist {
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#sidenav {
 background-color: yellow;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
 overflow: scroll;
 padding: 8px;
}
#topnav {
 background-color: red;
 border-bottom: 2px solid white;
 grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}
.track {
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 display: flex;
 height: 32px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <body>
  <div id="topnav"></div>
  <div id="sidenav"></div>
  <div id="mainnav">
   <div id="playlist">
    <div class="track">
     <div class="clipdiv" style="left: 50%;">
      <canvas class="clip" width="417" height="128"></canvas>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track"></div>
    <div class="track"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am hoping to allow the pink clip's left position to exceed the width of the tracks, but force the tracks to change their width so they are always the size of the green div. Sorry for confusion, I am bad at explaining

Comment: In that snippet, the blue divs are always the full width of the green one.

Comment: This is true, but if the pink div's position is greater than the blue divs, they still remain the same size - e.g. if clipdiv has style="left: 640px;", the blue divs are still the same width

Comment: If you want the width of the blue divs to be dynamic, you should be changing their width directly.

Comment: I will use JavaScript to resize instead if this is the only option.